# How to split screen width into two parts for swipe gestures

Tags: android, android-studio, swipe, exoplayer, swipe-gesture

I am developing video player app using Exoplayer and applying swipe gestures for volume and brightness. Swipe gesture for top,bottom,right,left are working well.
But i want to split width into two parts for volume and brightness features separately, suggest me extra code for doing this.
This is my code for OnSwipeTouchListner.java

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    ///below first one is downEvent second is moveEvent
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    onSwipeBottom();
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop();
                }
                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}}
```

Below code is implementation in Main Activity

```
playerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this){
        public void onSwipeTop() {
            Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To check which part of your screen is touched ( left part or right part ), first try by calculating the screen's width and height inside onDown:

```
screen_width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
screen_height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Create 2 booleans:

```
private boolean isLeft;
private boolean isRight;
```

```
@Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("TAG","onDown: ");
            screen_width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            screen_height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            
            if (event.getX() < (screen_width / 2)) {
                // isLeft means the left side is touched
                isLeft = true;
                isRight = false;

            } else if (event.getX() > (screen_width / 2)) {
                // isRight means the right side is touched
                isLeft = false;
                isRight = true;
            }
            // don't return false here
            // or else none of the other gestures will work
            return true;
        }
```

Then use the booleans as you wish:

```
if (isRight) {

} else if (isLeft) {

}
```